# How to update table values using regular expression?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi is it possible to update email and website links using regular expression.
in my wordpress post meta table I loss all metakey values. I have the meta values only. is it possible to check the meta value like email or site links using regular expression and update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html